# PHP - Cookies are being removed, but are regenerated on the next page

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have an option for users to select a "Remember me" option on my site that saves certain information to cookies so that they can be authenticated without needing to log in.

However, when users want to log out, it seems that these cookies are being deleted, but are for some reason being created again when they are sent to the next page.

The following is an example of my log out script. Before this exact code is called, the user is authenticated via a different file included in the log out file and cookies are set if the user has specified that they wish to be remembered.

```php
// -- FROM THE AUTH FILE -- //

setcookie("username", "bob240", time() + (86400 * 30), "/", ".domain.com");
setcookie("password", "password123", time() + (86400 * 30), "/", ".domain.com");

// -- END FROM THE AUTH FILE -- //

// Clear cookies by setting them to a past date.
setcookie("username", "", time() - (86400 * 30), "/", ".domain.com");
setcookie("password", "", time() - (86400 * 30), "/", ".domain.com");

// Check if the session was destroyed.
if(session_destroy()) {

    // Redirect the user.
    header('Location: /next/page/'); die("Redirecting...");

}
```

This means that the same cookies are set twice on the same page. However, because these cookies are set in the order from which they are listed, there should not be any conflicts.

However, to test this theory, I tracked the header requests and responses from my browser and I could see that the cookies were being set when the user was authenticated and deleted when the user logged out.

To check further, I printed $_SESSION and $_COOKIE multiple times on the log out page and the page the user was redirected to. I could see that the cookies were being removed, as $_COOKIE was empty. However, $_SESSION still contained the necessary information to authenticate the user. Because of this, I thought that the sessions were somehow causing the problem. However, I threw away this thought when I tested logging out without the cookies being set from the "Remember me" option, and everything worked fine.

I also want to note that when visiting the log out page from a sub-domain, going from sub-domain.domain.com -> www.domain.com/log-out-page/, I was able to successfully log out even with cookies set.

I am also able to sometimes successfully log out after visiting the log out page multiple times.

I use the same code (AFAIK) on two others sites, which are both on the same web servers, and everything is working fine. I even tried using the files from the other two sites, but the problem still persists. All of these sites use CloudFlare and have the same settings set.

Since this is a very vague issue, you can use the demo account on my site to log in and test anything yourself.

Site that isn't working: https://theartex.net/system/login/,
site that is working: https://mathhulk.me/system/login/

Account:
username - demo,
password - demo

Comment: I just tested my site on three browsers. I seem to be having this problem on both Chrome and Edge, but can successfully log out from Safari on an iPad.

Comment: I did some more testing. Asked another user to login from the demo account on his PC and he had the same issue. However, I also tested this from my other laptop and I was able to successfully log out. This seems to be a vary weird issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant pinging of `/cloud/api/` to get the alerts for the user sets the cookies at the same time as `/system/logout` removes them. If you keep `/cloud/api` from setting the two cookies then it should all work again.

Comment: Always one to help me out @AL_1.